# Doing a count MySQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot

I have the following table:

```
UID | ID  | Type
1   | 1   | product
1   | 2   | product
1   | 3   | service
1   | 4   | product
1   | 5   | product
2   | 6   | service
1   | 7   | order
2   | 8   | invoice
2   | 9   | product
```

I want to end up with:

```
UID | product | service | invoice | order
1   |  4      |  1      |  0      |  1
2   |  1      |  1      |  1      |  0
```

What would the SQL query look like? Or at least, the most sufficient one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really only need those four types, then you can hard-code the values as follows:

```
select UID,
    count(case when type='product' then 1 else null end) as product,
    count(case when type='service' then 1 else null end) as service,
    count(case when type='invoice' then 1 else null end) as invoice,
    count(case when type='order' then 1 else null end) as order
from MyTable
group by UID
order by UID
```

Answer (score 7):

What you want to do is a pivot operation, which is not directly supported by SQL syntax. However, it's not too complicated, and conceptually involves 2 steps:

1. "Blow up" the data into many columns, with one row per row in the original data set. This is usually done with CASE WHEN ... ELSE ... END or occasionally with functions (like decode() in oracle). I'll use CASE WHEN in the example below, since it works equally well for most RDBMSes
2. Use GROUP BY and aggregate functions (SUM, MIN, MAX, etc) to collapse the many rows into the output row set you want.

I'm using this data set for the example:

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+------+------+---------+
| uid  | id   | type    |
+------+------+---------+
|    1 |    1 | product | 
|    1 |    2 | product | 
|    1 |    3 | service | 
|    1 |    4 | product | 
|    1 |    5 | product | 
|    2 |    6 | service | 
|    1 |    7 | order   | 
|    2 |    8 | invoice | 
|    2 |    9 | product | 
+------+------+---------+
```

Step 1 is to "blow up" the data set:

```
select uid
     , case when type = 'product' then 1 else 0 end as is_product
     , case when type = 'service' then 1 else 0 end as is_service
     , case when type = 'invoice' then 1 else 0 end as is_invoice
     , case when type = 'order' then 1 else 0 end as is_order
  from foo;
```

which gives:

```
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| uid  | is_product | is_service | is_invoice | is_order |
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
|    1 |          1 |          0 |          0 |        0 | 
|    1 |          1 |          0 |          0 |        0 | 
|    1 |          0 |          1 |          0 |        0 | 
|    1 |          1 |          0 |          0 |        0 | 
|    1 |          1 |          0 |          0 |        0 | 
|    2 |          0 |          1 |          0 |        0 | 
|    1 |          0 |          0 |          0 |        1 | 
|    2 |          0 |          0 |          1 |        0 | 
|    2 |          1 |          0 |          0 |        0 | 
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
```

Next we collapse to one row in the output per date, and sum each of the is_* columns, using or initial query as an inline view (aka a "subquery"):

```
select uid
     , sum(is_product) as count_product
     , sum(is_service) as count_service
     , sum(is_invoice) as count_invoice
     , sum(is_order)   as count_order
  from (
         select uid
              , case when type = 'product' then 1 else 0 end as is_product
              , case when type = 'service' then 1 else 0 end as is_service
              , case when type = 'invoice' then 1 else 0 end as is_invoice
              , case when type = 'order' then 1 else 0 end as is_order
           from foo
       ) x
 group by uid;
```

(Note also that you can collapse these two queries into one, though I've shown them separately here for clarity; In MySQL at least, this seems to result in a simpler execution plan, which often means faster execution -- as always, test your SQL performance on realistic data sets, don't take my word for it!)

This gives us:

```
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+
| uid  | count_product | count_service | count_invoice | count_order |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+
|    1 |             4 |             1 |             0 |           1 | 
|    2 |             1 |             1 |             1 |           0 | 
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Which is the desired result.

Comment: I will have to try this method as well. Would you say this is more efficient than OrbMan's suggestion?

Comment: OrbMan's solution is essentially the "collapsed" version to which I referred... he uses count and nulls rather than sum, but basically takes the same steps. As for which is more efficient, you'll have to try both on your table and find out. Also, EXPLAIN ANALYZE can help figure out what MySQL is doing and how long it might take.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [CASE statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) in MySQL to turn row data into columns (and vice versa):

```
  SELECT t.uid,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'product' THEN COUNT(*) END) as PRODUCT,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'service' THEN COUNT(*) END) as SERVICE,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'invoice' THEN COUNT(*) END) as INVOICE,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'order' THEN COUNT(*) END) as ORDER
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.uid, t.type
```

Comment: That gets part of the way there -- each row will only have the count for one of those columns. I think if you wrap it in another query, and do "select max(product) ... group by uid" it will get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something called a "pivot table", which isn't something MySQL can do natively.

You're probably best off, in this case, transforming the data in your application and using some combination of GROUP BY and/or DISTINCT to collect the data you're looking for.  This query might work, I have not tested it:

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(ID), UID
  FROM tablename
 GROUP BY UID, Type
```

Comment: Didn't he want to have the Type column values as the column headers if I believe what's written in the question?

Comment: This outputs it in a slightly different way. I.e. row for row, instead of everything in one row. But it'll do the trick! Thanks!

Comment: @will, Its true. I cant mark this as right, as it doesnt answer my question. It certainly helped tho.

Comment: MySQL does UNIONS properly.  As stated in my answer, what he really wants is a pivot table, but MySQL doesn't do those.  This is a workaround for that limitation.

Answer (score -3):

select count(product, service, invoice, order) from mytable