# SQL How to group data that matches values?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to re-use a query that was for data ranges for this...basically I'm trying to get information on how many people were invited by the "value". People put this information into their profiles when they sign up and I want to fish it out. I have no idea what I'm doing :).

I'm hoping someone can take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong, which I understand could be the entire query lol.

The error I get is: *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END) as noone, count(CASE WHEN `variable` = 'invited' AND 'value' = 'noone'' at line 2*.

```
    select
     count(CASE WHEN `variable` = `invited` AND `value` = `no one` END) as noone,
     count(CASE WHEN `variable` = `invited` AND `value` = `noone` END) as noone,
     count(CASE WHEN `variable` = `invited` AND `value` = `bunny` END) as bunny,
     count(CASE WHEN `variable` = `invited` AND `value` = `jade` END) as bunny,
     count(CASE WHEN `variable` = `invited` AND `value` = `bunnyrabbitsex` END) as bunnyrabbitsex,
     count(CASE WHEN `variable` = `invited` AND `value` = `google` END) as google,
     count(CASE WHEN `variable` = `invited` AND `value` = `twitter` END) as twitter,
     count(CASE WHEN `variable` = `invited` AND `value` = `plurk` END) as plurk,
     count(CASE WHEN `variable` = `invited` AND `value` = `facebook` END) as facebook,
     count(CASE WHEN `variable` = `invited` AND `value` = `advertisement` END) as advertisement,
from
    smf_themes
```

Comment: You are missing the `THEN` part in your `CASE` expressions. The answer from @kgu87 seems a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
  value, 
  count(*)
from
 smf_themes
where 
  variable = 'invited'
group by
  value
```

Comment: OMG You are amazing! Thank you SO MUCH!! That will help me with so so many queries in the future!!

Answer (score 2):

You need probably something like this :

[Doing a count MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482115/doing-a-count-mysql-query)

```
SELECT
count(CASE WHEN `variable` = `invited` AND `value` = `no one`  
           THEN 1 
           ELSE NULL END) as noone,
......
FROM smf_themes
```